# ambiguous [grok] tag

Tags: discussion, tag-disambiguation

The [current definition](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/grok/info) of the [grok](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/grok) tag refers to a web framework written in Python, but [most](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/grok) of the questions actually refer to an Elasticsearch plugin also called [grok](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/plugins-filters-grok.html). Some users are also tagging the questions with the [elasticsearch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/elasticsearch) tag, but I think a new tag [elasticsearch-grok](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/elasticsearch-grok) would be better.

What are your opinions?

Comment: I could see both sides to this. However, I would agree with you overall. There is already a `logstash-grok` tag (meaning this mentality has already been applied to this tag once), and this is very similar to the differences between `vba` and the others like `excel-vba` (and they even mean the same thing).

Comment: I don't [grok] this tag.

Comment: I think it's certainly worth disambiguating this from the more common [definition in programming culture](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Grok#In_computer_programmer_culture) which is used to indicate an understanding of something. You may even see "grok talks" at conferences.